# Ordering the content of on array with NodeJS and lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array like this:

```
[
  'pathOne/pathTwo/contentOne',
  'pathOne/pathThree/pathFour/contentTwo',
  'pathOne/pathThree/contentFive',
  'pathFive/pathThree/contentThree',
  'pathOne/pathTwo/contentFour'
]
```

I'm looking to have a string in alpha order and content first before the next sub-level:

pathFive

- pathThree

  - contentThree

pathOne

- pathThree

  - contentFive (Content before sub-level)
  - pathFour
  - contentTwo (One more level)
- pathTwo

  - contentFour
  - contentOne

I started to get this inside an array with lodash to do easiest operation on it but i couldn't get this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for it to just sort the array or explode it into a nested object? Can you convert your desired result into a code format with exactly your desired result so it's clearer?

Comment: search sorting algorithm, there are tons of them.

Comment: Yes in a object is fine too, i can after get all datas.

Comment: I did a foreach then a split `_.split(value, '/');` like this i have each row inside an array. Now trying to do again a foreach and push into a new array but i don't know how to do when i need to put content and next sub-level (Case pathOne - pathThree).

Answer (score 0):

Trying many things i found finally what i wanted.

```
var object = {};

var test = [
    'pathOne/pathTwo/contentTwo',
    'pathOne/pathTwo/contentOne',
    'pathOne/contentThree',
    'pathOne/pathThree/pathFour/contentFour'
];

Object.resolve = function(path, obj) {
    return path.split('.').reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev ? prev[curr] : undefined
    }, obj || self)
}

_.forEach(test, function(value) {
    var arrayPath = _.split(value, '/');
    var file = arrayPath.pop();

    if(Object.resolve(arrayPath.join('.'), object) === undefined)
      arrayPath.push(0);
    else
      arrayPath.push(arrayPath.length-1);

    _.set(object, arrayPath, file);
});

console.log(object);
```